# Problem with Javascript Form to work consistently with Ajax to login to a Private Magento Store

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, magento

My Webdeveloper abandoned me and my form doesn't seem to work always.

When clicked it doesn't appear to do anything (just shows the "javascript:;" href on the browser status bar), but sometimes it works...

I've searched everywhere for a solution but I haven't had any luck. Maybe I don't know where to start!! Really would appreciate help: I'm a novice and have been struggling. THANK YOU!!

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js" ></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function login(){
             if($('username').value == '') alert('Username cannot be left blank');
             if($('password').value == '') alert('Password cannot be left blank');
      new Ajax.Request('http://www.website.com/index.php/customer/account/ajaxLogin',
      {
   method:'post',
      parameters: 'username='+$('username').value+'&password='+$('password').value,
         onSuccess: function(transport){
             if (transport && transport.responseText){
      try{
         response = eval('(' + transport.responseText + ')');
         }
     catch (e) {
    response = {};
     }
   }

   if (response.success){
                           location.href="http://www.website.com/index.php"
   }else{
       if ((typeof response.message) == 'string') {
    alert(response.message);
       } 
       return false;
   }
 },
   onFailure: function(){ alert('Something went wrong...') }
   });
 }
   </script>
      </head>
```

**This is the HTML form**

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="#" id="frm">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="text" class="rounded" name="username" id="username" value="Username" /></li>
        <li><input type="password" class="rounded" name="password" id="password" value="Password" /></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:;" onClick="login();return false;"><img src="splash/button.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                   </ul>
</form>
```

Callup of prototype.js refers to prototype.js MIT Javascript framework, version 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

try changing this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onClick="login();return false;">
```

into this:

```
<a href="javascript:login();return false;">
```

I hope it'll help

**edit:**
It seems that your JS code has been written badly too. Lets consider lines:

```
     if($('username').value == '') alert('Username cannot be left blank');
     if($('password').value == '') alert('Password cannot be left blank');
```

Even when the login fields are left blank a request is going to be sent. Change to:

```
     if($('username').value == '') {
              alert('Username cannot be left blank');
              return false;
     }
     if($('password').value == '') {
              alert('Password cannot be left blank');
              return false;
     }
```

Other things should be fine.